# Change font type in Clean Thesis version v0.4.1 2020/06/17

Tags: fonts, cleanthesis

I am using the clean thesis template to write a thesis. Which looks good, however, I want to change the font of the main text to *comicneue*.

Eddited: I am passing the option to use sans-serif in the package options: \PassOptionsToPackage{...., sansserif=true,...}{cleanthesis}

Also, I found the code section in cleanthesis.sty where it supposes the template do the change from Serif to Sans-Serif, using the define font types:

```
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}        % font types and character verification
% \ifthenelse{\boolean{@sansserif}}%
\ifct@cthesis@sansserif
%   {
% Using sans-serif fonts
%       \RequirePackage{helvet}
%       \RequirePackage{opensans}
%       \RequirePackage{comicneue}
        \RequirePackage{libertine}
%       \RequirePackage{tgadventor}
        \renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}%
%   }{%
\else
        % Using serif fonts
%       \RequirePackage{lmodern}    % font set: Latin Modern
%       \RequirePackage{charter}    % font set: Charter
%   }
\fi
```

I uncommented the code so the template uses *comicneue* as the SS font type. However, for some reason, the font does not change.

I changed it to libertine to check if the code was working, and yes, the font changes:
[image]

But when I change it to *comicneue*, the font "returns" to what it looks to me as a default sans serif font for scrreprt class (I do not know if this is true).

[image]

I tried both, with and without [default] option when loading the package but in no vail.

More than the specific *comicneue* font type, what I'm looking for is to use a font type in the main text that makes the letters **a** and **g** appear like we do it by hand. So, also I also tried with *TEX Gyre Adventor    tgadventor  qag* but with no vail. What it is interesting is that I am using the same qag font type for chapter and section font and the template accepts it, but not for the main text.

```
\newcommand{\tgherosfont}{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\thesischapterfont}{\color{ctcolorblack}\nobreak\normalfont\huge\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\thesissectionfont}{\color{ctcolorsection}\nobreak\normalfont\Large\tgherosfont}
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Post the actual code in a code block. Is there a way to get the clean thesis template without an Overleaf account? Hard to test without it. Most likely you want to use `\usepackage` in your own document rather `\RequirePackage` modifying the document class or package. The comicneue package only sets it as the default font if you pass it the default option. `\usepackage[default]{comicneue}`. But as a professor, can I beg you *not* to your thesis in that horrific font? I think I'd fail my student outright for that alone.

Comment: OK I think I found the template [here](http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/): is that it? `\usepackage[default]{comicneue}` right before `\begin{document}` in my-thesis.tex works to set the default, but the template often switches to other fonts (charter, sans, etc.). Do you want it *everywhere*? Are you using the sansserif option? (Honestly, that looks like the least "clean" template I can imagine.)

Comment: Yes, it is that template. And yes, I am passing the option to use sans-serif in the package options: 
\PassOptionsToPackage{...., sansserif=true,...}{cleanthesis}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cleanthesis.sty` we find

```
% own font definitions
\newcommand{\helv}{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\book}{\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{m}\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\tgherosfont}{\fontfamily{qhv}\selectfont}

\newcommand{\thesispartlabelfont}{\color{ctcolorpartnum}\nobreak\book\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\thesispartfont}{\color{ctcolorparttext}\nobreak\normalfont\huge \tgherosfont\selectfont}
\newcommand{\thesischapterfont}{\color{ctcolorblack}\nobreak\normalfont\huge \fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
%\newcommand{\thesissectionfont}{\color{ctcolormain}\nobreak\LARGE\bfseries \tgherosfont}
\newcommand{\thesissectionfont}{\color{ctcolorsection}\nobreak\normalfont\LARGE \tgherosfont}
\newcommand{\thesissubsectionfont}{\color{ctcolorsubsection}\nobreak\normalfont\Large \tgherosfont}
\newcommand{\thesisparagraphfont}{\color{ctcolorparagraph}\nobreak\tgherosfont\small\bfseries}

\newcommand{\ctfontfooterpagenumber}{%
    \color{ctcolorfooterpage}%
    \normalfont\normalsize\bfseries \tgherosfont%
}
\newcommand{\ctfontfootertext}{%
    \color{ctcolorfootertitle}%
    \normalfont\footnotesize \tgherosfont%
}
%
% headings
\setkomafont{part}{\thesispartfont} % for chapter entries
\setkomafont{chapter}{\thesischapterfont} % for chapter entries
\setkomafont{section}{\thesissectionfont} % for section entries
\setkomafont{subsection}{\thesissubsectionfont} % for section entries
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\tgherosfont}
%\addtokomafont{paragraph}{\tgherosfont}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\thesisparagraphfont}
```

which is really disputable. It's not clear why `qbk` (Bookman) is used for parts: it's a serif font really incompatible with any of the other choices. Why alternating between `phv` (Helvetica) and `qhv` (Heros)? Why the obviously wrong `\nobreak` commands?

You might want to change the definitions of the fonts for the sectional titles to use `\normalfont`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[
  sansserif,
]{cleanthesis}
\usepackage[default]{comicneue}

\renewcommand{\thesispartlabelfont}{\color{ctcolorpartnum}\fontsize{60}{60}\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\thesispartfont}{\color{ctcolorparttext}\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\thesischapterfont}{\color{ctcolorblack}\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\thesissectionfont}{\color{ctcolorsection}\normalfont\LARGE}
\renewcommand{\thesissubsectionfont}{\color{ctcolorsubsection}\normalfont\Large}
\renewcommand{\thesisparagraphfont}{\color{ctcolorparagraph}\normalfont\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\ctfontfooterpagenumber}{\color{ctcolorfooterpage}\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\ctfontfootertext}{\color{ctcolorfootertitle}\normalfont\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

This is a test

\section{Test}

This is a test

\end{document}
```

[image]

This said, a thesis is a ***SERIOUS*** document. While ComicNeue is not as ugly as ComicSans, it is ***completely inappropriate*** for a serious document.

Would you like to see the Constitution of your country printed that way? Or do you believe that anybody would even think to print a Papal Bull in ComicNeue? Your thesis is the achievement of years of study, don't ridicule it.

Are you ready to accept raised eyebrows or even laughs when the committee starts to examine your thesis? I don't think so.

Leave alone `cleanthesis`. It's badly written. If you insist, leave alone the `sansserif` option. And keep those redefinitions, so the fonts for titles are not set in some random font.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{cleanthesis}
\usepackage{cochineal}

\renewcommand{\thesispartlabelfont}{\color{ctcolorpartnum}\fontsize{60}{60}\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\thesispartfont}{\color{ctcolorparttext}\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\thesischapterfont}{\color{ctcolorblack}\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\thesissectionfont}{\color{ctcolorsection}\normalfont\LARGE}
\renewcommand{\thesissubsectionfont}{\color{ctcolorsubsection}\normalfont\Large}
\renewcommand{\thesisparagraphfont}{\color{ctcolorparagraph}\normalfont\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\ctfontfooterpagenumber}{\color{ctcolorfooterpage}\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\ctfontfootertext}{\color{ctcolorfootertitle}\normalfont\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

This is a test

\section{Test}

This is a test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg. I manage to run it with Sans serif fonts in the main text. However, based on your and @frabjous comments, I have decided to not use SS fonts for the main text. I am sticking to Charter for the normal text and TEX Gyre Adventor for titles.